# JSX not creating files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file src/post.jsx with the following content

```
var React = require('react');

var Post = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>I am a t!!!</h1>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = Post;
React.render(
  <Post />,
  document.getElementById('post')
);
```

When I run

```
jsx --watch src/  build/\
```

only the build directory gets created but no post.js file.

Do I have to run some other command first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsx` only seems to consider `*.js` files [by default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tools):

```
-x, --extension <js | coffee | ...>      File extension to assume when resolving module identifiers (default: js)
```

So, add `-x jsx`.